# Does being the spouse of a US citizen help a non-EU citizen obtain a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, usa, schengen, us-citizens, thailand

I am a US citizen and a resident of Thailand. My Thai wife and I are planning on travelling to France for three weeks for our honeymoon. We just held the social wedding ceremony, but haven't applied for our marriage certificate with the local district office yet.

She is employed by a multinational company in Bangkok, but I'm afraid her salary might not be high enough to meet minimum visa requirements.

Will the fact that she is married to a US national be taken into account when applying for a Schengen visa?

Comment: You aren't "married" until you have the marriage certificate from the district office.  Best get that underway as your certification as eligible to marry can take time if you live outside Bangkok.

Answer (score 2):

If she had been a US resident, she would've been deemed a lower-risk traveller, although the same procedure would be in place.

But no, she should provide the exact same documentation as "ordinarily" stipulated, and needs to meet the exact same requirements.

Submit as much proof as you can that you as a couple will have enough money to spend on your honeymoon without engaging in illegal employment, and she should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Formally, it will not make a difference that she is married to a US citizen. Practically, it will most likely give her a great advantage, as the consular officer ultimately will evaluate her ability to finance the trip and her willingness to leave the Schengen area after having being granted entry.

Assuming that the consulate considers your relationship genuine (it may actually be a problem if you don't have an official marriage certificate yet):

- It will not be an issue that your wife herself has not the financial means to pay for the trip if you have. It will be a relatively common situation that married couples apply for a visa for common travel and only one part has a sufficient income or financial means to pay for und justify the cost of travel. You might be required to sign an affidavit to declare your liability for any costs incurred during travel.
- I would also assume that being married to a non-EEA citizen will be an advantage. After all, you yourself cannot stay indefinitely in the EEA, so her willingness to stay together with you after the trip, is likely to reduce the risk of her overstaying illegaly (without you).

Comment: Last but not least, the marriage should put her on the track towards getting legal residence in the US. That makes illegal residence in the EU appear less likely.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately no. The fact that she is married to an American (who has visa free entry to Schengen states) has no effect on her Schengen visa application. Even if she were a Permanent Resident of the USA, which she is not yet, it wouldn't have any effect. Your privileges do not transfer to your spouse.

She would still have to satisfy the requirements for a Schengen visa that a typical Thai citizen has to satisfy.